# Rspec test cases fails Failure/Error: fake_login SystemExit: exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

i'm working on a project and coding for test cases, every thing is fine but when i run whole test cases by

**bundle exec rspec acceptance**          .: acceptance is the folder where i have specs.rb files

many of test cases fails and give error

**Error:
 Failure/Error: fake_login
     SystemExit:
       exit**

Any clue or help as i think this is not test case error.

Comment: run separate test cases for that and check error comes or not and send test cases

Comment: What is `fake_login`? Posting that might help us see the problem.

Comment: Failure/Error: visit homepage
     SystemExit:
       exit
see this previous resolved..i dont know why but i just rerun..now this is error

Comment: Bricker, i'm getting this error for a bunch of test cases can u plz tell me a good way to get rid from this..... Rack application timed out during boot